# Numbering points on a line based on their position without checking all positions.

Tags: geometry

I have a line that contains atleast 2 points, the start and finish.  There could also be points within the two.

Given are the amount of points, and their position along the line.
I must label each point numerically based on its position along the line.
If there is 3 points, one at the start, one in the middle, and one at the finish, these points need to be named 1, 2, and 3.

The question is, how can you determine what its numerical label should be based only on its position (between 0 and 100) and the total length of points in the line.

I've gotten close to solving it but not exact, the tricky thing is giving it a label without checking the other points as well.  I have to give it a correct label with only its position and the total amount of points.

What I came up with and is close:
(lengthOfPoints / (100 * lengthOfPoints) - (pointPosition * lengthOfPoints) / 100))

Any idea how to pull this off would be of great help to me.  I've been trying to solve this for the past 6 hours.

Comment: By the way, the length of the line is always 100.

Comment: What makes you think this is possible? The point located at 50, say, could be the second point, or it could be the next-to-last point, or anything in between. You can't know without checking the other points, can you?

Comment: I don't know if its possible, I figured that given the total amount of points and the current position of one point there must be a way to number where the point is along the line.... if the amount of points was not given then no way... but with that there should be a way to guess.  Also considering the length of the line is given as well it should be possible.  If only I were a math genius....

Comment: Wait – you're not assuming the points are equally spaced along the line, are you?

Comment: @GerryMyerson -  No, points most likely would not be evenly spaced.  I think you may be correct on it being impossible to know without checking the other points.

Comment: @OB7DEV: If you have the positions of the points, sorted by position, you only need to check roughly $O(\log_2 N)$ values to find the closest lower/higher point and its number, when there are $N$ points, by using a binary search. You just are not giving us enough information to give you a better answer, really. It all so very much depends on the exact details, you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have $N$ equally spaced points, numbered $1$ to $N$, with point $1$ at position $L_0$, and point $N$ at position $L_1$, then point $i$ is at position

$$x_i = L_0 + \frac{i-1}{N-1} \left ( L_1 - L_0 \right)$$

See the resemblance to [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)? That's how I constructed it.

If we solve the above for $i$, we find that the number at position $x$ is

$$i = 1 + \frac{(x - L_0)(N - 1)}{L_1 - L_0}$$

If $L_0 = 0$ and $L_1 = L$, those simplify to
$$x_i = \frac{i-1}{N-1} L$$
and
$$i = 1 + \frac{x \; L}{N - 1}$$

---

The OP has a JavaScript project with non-equally spaced points.

For this case, I recommend using an array with the points sorted by value, so that a binary search can be used to very efficiently find the correct (exact or closest) point to a given value.

Here is an example (wrapped in HTML for easy testing) of how to use binary search to find the correct or nearest label in *O(log<sub>2</sub> N)* time. In practice, it means you can easily have thousands of labels in a range, and the functions are not much slower than when you have, say, dozen.

This example is of course in public domain ([CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)).

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> JavaScript range with labels </title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <style type="text/css">
   html, body { color: #000000; background: #ffffff; }
   .highlight { background: #99ccff; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var labels = [];

    /* Add a label object. You can add other properties as needed.
       If overwrite is true, overwrites an existing label with the same
       value. If false, and a label with that value already exists,
       the existing label is kept. Returns true if added to array. */
    function addLabel(value, label, overwrite)
    {
        var imin = 0;
        var imax = labels.length - 1;
        var newLabel = { value:value, label:label };

        /* No labels yet? After last existing label? */
        if (imax < 0 || labels[imax].value < value) {
            labels.push(newLabel);
            return true;
        }

        /* Before first existing label? */
        if (value < labels[0].value) {
            labels.unshift(newLabel);
            return true;
        }

        /* Replace first existing label? */
        if (value == labels[0].value) {
            if (!overwrite)
                return false;
            labels[0] = newLabel;
            return true;
        }

        /* Replace last existing label? */
        if (value == labels[imax].value) {
            if (!overwrite)
                return false;
            labels[imax] = newLabel;
            return true;
        }

        /* Binary search to find insertion point. */
        while (imax - imin > 1) {
            var i = imin + Math.floor((imax - imin)/2);

            if (labels[i].value < value)
                imin = i;
            else
            if (labels[i].value > value)
                imax = i;
            else {
                /* Found at [i]. */
                if (!overwrite)
                    return false;
                labels[i] = newLabel;
                return true;
            }
        }

        /* Not found. Insert after imin. */
        labels.splice(imin + 1, 0, newLabel);
        return true;
    }

    /* Delete (and return) a label with the specified value. */
    function delLabel(value)
    {
        var imin = 0;
        var imax = labels.length - 1;

        /* No labels? */
        if (imax < 0)
            return null;

        /* Outside the array range? */
        if (value < labels[imin].value ||
            value > labels[imax].value)
            return null;

        /* First? */
        if (value == labels[imin].value)
            return labels.shift();

        /* Last? */
        if (value == labels[imax].value)
            return labels.pop();

        /* Binary search. */
        while (imax - imin > 1) {
            var i = imin + (imax - imin) / 2;

            if (labels[i].value < value)
                imin = i;
            else
            if (labels[i].value > value)
                imax = i;
            else {
                found = labels[i];

                /* Remove [i] */
                labels.splice(i, 0);

                /* Return the label removed from the array. */
                return found;
            }
        }

        /* Not found. */
        return null;
    }

    /* Find and return the label closest to value. */
    function closestLabel(value)
    {
        var imin = 0;
        var imax = labels.length - 1;

        /* No labels? */
        if (imax < 0)
            return null;

        /* Before or at first label? */
        if (value <= labels[imin].value)
            return labels[imin];

        /* At or after last label? */
        if (value >= labels[imax].value)
            return labels[imax];

        /* Binary search. */
        while (imax - imin > 1) {
            var i = imin + Math.floor((imax - imin)/2);

            if (labels[i].value < value)
                imin = i;
            else
            if (labels[i].value > value)
                imax = i;
            else
                return labels[i];        
        }

        /* Pick the closer one. */
        if (value - labels[imin].value <= labels[imax].value - value)
            return labels[imin];
        else
            return labels[imax];
    }

    /* The following are needed only for the example user interface. */
    function ui_list(val)
    {
        var n = labels.length;
        var html = [];

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (val === labels[i].value)
                html.push("<tt class=\"highlight\">{ value: ");
            else
                html.push("<tt>{ value: ");
            html.push(labels[i].value, ", label:\"", labels[i].label, "\" }</tt><br>\n");
        }

        document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = html.join("");
    }

    function ui_exact()
    {
        var val = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value").value);
        var item = closestLabel(val);

        if (item !== null && item.value === val)
            ui_list(val);
        else
            ui_list(null);
    }

    function ui_closest()
    {
        var val = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value").value);
        var item = closestLabel(val);

        if (item !== null)
            ui_list(item.value);
        else
            ui_list(null);
    }

    function ui_add()
    {
        var value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value").value);
        var label = document.getElementById("label").value;

        if (addLabel(value, label, false))
            ui_list(null);

        document.getElementById("label").value = "";
    }

    function ui_delete()
    {
        var value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value").value);
        if (delLabel(value))
            ui_list(null);
    }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <form method="GET" action="#">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Labels</legend>
    <div id="table"></div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Actions</legend>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="ui_delete();">
    <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="ui_add();">
    <input id="value" type="text" value="" size="5" title="Value">
    <input id="label" type="text" value="" size="10" title="Label">
    <input type="button" value="Find Exact" onClick="ui_exact();">
    <input type="button" value="Find Closest" onClick="ui_closest();">
   </fieldset>
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

If you save the above as a HTML file, and open it in your browser, fill in the two text boxes with a value (a number) and a label (some text), and click the Add button. All the other buttons only use the value text box (smaller one, on the left). If a label matching some value is found, it is highlighted.

For further info on binary search, start at the [Binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) Wikipedia page.

Note that the above implementation does not allow more than one label with the same value. If you allow duplicate values, a binary search finds one of them, but not necessarily the first one, so a bit of additional code (finding the leftmost of multiple matches) is needed then. I don't think multiple labels for the same value are that useful, though.

Since a binary search only works on a sorted array, the array is *always* kept in sorted order. This lets us do insertion and deletion with the JS array `.splice()` method; we only need to find the insertion point (index in the array) -- for which we can again use a binary search.

Note that I effectively duplicated the binary search code. This is not good practice. One should write it just once in a separate helper function (returning the array index `i`, or `-1` if not found, for example), which would also make testing easier. (If you copy and paste the same bit of code, and later on fix a problem in only some of them, you're going to feel pain trying to find the ensuing bugs..)

However, in this particular example I decided to make an exception, and copy-paste the code into the functions, so that the logic would be easier to follow.

Comment: What if the points are not equally spaced?

Comment: @OB7DEV: It depends on several factors. If there is a monotonic function $f(y)$, so that each position $x_i$ fulfills $f(a y + b) \le x_i \lt f(a y + a + b)$ -- i.e. you can place separators $y_i$ according to some function so that for all $i = 1 .. N$, $y_i \le x_i \lt y_{i+i}$, you can use the inverse for $y_i$ and round down to solve for $i$. If this is implemented in a program, there are various algorithms that can be used to make this fast; it just depends on whether you want the result at the exact $x_i$, or the nearest (or next not greater/lower) $x_i$ relative to some point $x$.

Comment: my question was initially prompted because I am writing a program.  In programming, its nice when you can determine something in one line of code instead of looping through a set of items.  I hoped to make a one liner to give my points a label, but due to the amount of time it was taking I decided to just loop through all the points once to store their positions and then a second time to label them accordingly.  Your answers are very helpful though, I must say you are the math genius I could only dream of becoming!

Comment: @OB7DEV: No, I just have practical experience with close enough stuff; my math-fu is not that strong. Which programming language are you using? I might be able to show you a simple solution.

Comment: This project is coded in javascript.

Comment: @OB7DEV: Okay; I added an example you can play with in a browser to my answer. It boils down to keeping the labels in an array sorted by the value, so you can use a fast binary search. (If you have say 1,000 items in an array, a binary search is about 100 times faster than a linear search; for 1,000,000 items, a binary search is 50,000 times faster.)